# Locating & Clicking button (Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to click the link in Selenium (Python 2.7). This is the HTML Code:

```
<div class="buttons">
        <a href="https://twitter.com/login?redirect_after_login=%2Flogout" class="btn cancel">Cancel</a>
        <button type="submit" class="btn primary-btn js-submit">Log out</button>
      </div>
```

I'm trying to click the "Log out" button. I've tried:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Log out").click()
```

But that didn't seem to work.

Any help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

*The "by link text" locator would only work with links - `a` elements*. Here you can use an XPath to check the text of the button:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[. = 'Log out']").click()
```

---

As a side note, in this code:

> `elem = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Log out").click()`

there is not much sense in assigning the result of `click()` to a variable - it'd always be `None`.